# How Can I Generate a POJO from an HTTP POST Request in a Spring Boot Application

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, jackson, unmarshalling

I have an `Angular 2` service that POSTs login data to a `Spring Boot` `@RestContoller`

The login request body:

```
{"_username": "test", "_password": "test"}
```

The Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class AuthControl {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public LoginDto authenticate(HttpServletResponse response, LoginRequestDto requestDto) throws IOException, JSONException {
        return authenticationService.authenticate(requestDto, response);
    }
}
```

Jackson unmarshalls the request into this POJO

```
public class LoginRequestDto {
    private String _username;
    private String _password;

    public LoginRequestDto() { }
    public LoginRequestDto(String u, String p) {
        this._username = u;
        this._password = p;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

However, when Jackson unmarshalls the POJO the field values are set to null, rather than "test"/"test". As a result, the login attempt fails with a bad credentials message. I'm wondering if i'm missing a library or something that is resulting in the improper setting of these fields.

Dependencies from `pom.xml`

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency><!-- implements Thymeleaf HTML5 parsing -->
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.22</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Tthe only exception logged is a UsernameNotFoundException thrown by my implmentation of Spring Security's UserDetailsService. Using the debugger, I can manually parse the values from the request and set the values into the POJO. After doing this, the request completes, so it seems clear that the issue is in the unmarshalling phase.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to Jackson using the default constructor, by default, when deserializing. You need to use the `@JsonCreator` annotation to let jackson know which the constructor you want to use is and the the annotation `@JsonProperty` to let it know how to bind the params with the json properties.

```
public class LoginRequestDto {
    private String _username;
    private String _password;

    public LoginRequestDto() { }

    @JsonCreator
    public LoginRequestDto(@JsonProperty("_username") String u,
                           @JsonProperty("_password") String p) {
        this._username = u;
        this._password = p;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

Have a look to the section ***Using constructors or factory methods*** at the [jackson-annotations project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations).

---

Update your request mapping method specifying it consumes json and add the @RequestBody annotation to the method param

```
@RestController
public class AuthControl {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationService authenticationService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/someurl", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public LoginDto authenticate(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody LoginRequestDto requestDto) throws IOException, JSONException {
        return authenticationService.authenticate(requestDto, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I added the annotations as suggested with no success. No change, default constructor still being called. Commenting out the default constructor reveals the reason - Spring creates the POJO argument. Is the only real option a custom deserializer?

Comment: @TheHeadRush What do you mean with "Spring creates the POJO"? It should work. You do not need a custom deserialiser for this, it is pretty basic. You are using an old version of jackson-datatype-son-org. Include dependencies for jackson-core, jackson-databind and jackson-annotations  (v2.8.6). Is your method being hit when you do the request? Are you setting the content-type header? It seems Spring thinks it does not have to convert the request body

Comment: When i say "Spring creates the POJO" i mean that intentionally failing POJO instantiation (by commenting out the default constructor) results in a stack trace containing no frames that reference Jackson. Updated the dependency for `jackson-datatype-son-org`. Added explicit dependencies to v2.8.6 of the three Jackson jars. The expected controller method is hit, content type header is set to "application/json". I'm baffled.

Comment: Adding the consumes argument and @RequestBody annotation solved the problem. Not sure why the additional annotation is needed, but that's beside the point. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TheHeadRush, if you do not use RequestBody Spring, by default, is going to try to bind the properties of your param with request parameters or objects at the model, so if you send a html form or use a url like /someurl?_username=xx&_password=xx you can not include that annotation. With RequestBody you are letting Spring know it needs to bind your parameter with the object coming in the payload. I hope you get it. http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html